# SQL Server -Order BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-order-by, varchar

I have a field in table that is varchar(12), however data in that field is a date - 1/1/2016 (I have about 5,000 dates). I've been trying to do an ORDER BY but it doesn't seem to order by the date. How would I go about doing ORDER BY on that field if it's not a DateTIME field??

Comment: Use the correct datatype and you won't have these problems. Why are you using `varchar` instead of `date`?

Comment: Can you provide the query you are trying? Then you will get the right answer.

Comment: Select firstName, LastName, ServiceStart, ServiceEnd from TblClients order by ServiceEnd desc. But vercelli answered it already so it's all set. thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
Order by cast(Field as datetime)
```

Comment: @LD16 Glad it helped. Gordon Linoff has a good point. Check his answer also.

Answer (score 3):

The conversion of a date such as "1/1/2016" using `CAST()` depends on localization  settings.

Assuming the value is in MM/DD/YYYY format (some countries do use DD/MM/YYYY), then this is more safely written as:

```
order by convert(datetime, field, 101)
```

Then, you run the risk that the conversion may fail, if a field does not exactly match this format.  To prevent this error, SQL Server 2012+ offers `try_convert()`.

So, I think the best approach is:

```
order by try_convert(datetime, field, 101)
```

Comment: . . . What's `101` ?

Comment: It is the silly method that SQL Server used to format dates before introducing `format()`.  It is a magic code, documented at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx.

Comment: Thankfully I only need this to query important data that is later copied. I'm not making any stored procedures or reusing it in code. thanks tho!